# Positive battery terminal is seized (rust or what not), can electrical work be still done with only the negative cable removed

Tags: battery, electronic-control-module, buick

Looks like positive would need to be cut out, it's completely locked shut.

Disconnected the negative. Will there be an issue with electrical work conducted, curious

Answer (score 2):

No problem as long as the negative is disconnected. You just have to disrupt the flow of electricity, which is what you've done by disconnecting the negative lead.

Comment: succeeded: no shorts, no fires, thank you!